# What should I do when catching InvalidOperationExcpetion during sql connection

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework

I can catch `InvalidOperationException` during the `.Open()` method of `SqlConnection`

```
Private Function InsertSomeData() As Boolean
    Using SqlCon As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Try
            SqlCon.Open()
        Catch sqlEx as SqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured while connecting to database!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.Ok, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Return False
        Catch invOpException As InvalidOperationExcpetion
            'what should go here? Connection is open so I just want to continue
        End Try

        'some more code
    End Using 
End Function
```

What should go in the commented area after `Catch`? I don't really want to log this even, just continue as connection is already open for some reason.

Comment: no, the connection is not open if that catch exception is reached.

Comment: Why are you catching that exception in the first place?  If you don't know what set of circumstances cause an exception to be thrown then you shouldn't be catching it. If you do know those circumstances then it's up to you to decide what to do about it.  You don't act on an exception.  You act on the circumstances that cause that exception to be thrown.